# Image text on code behind

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have some images in my project and there are text in those image which represents category in the project.
On mouse over of this image we can see the subcategories. Now problem i am suffering is , i am stuck on finding how the image text can be got in code behind.
Please help me to get a solution.

```
 <asp:Image  ID="Image1" runat="server" 
               ImageUrl="~/Images/New Bitmap Image(1).bmp" Width="180px" 
             CssClass="class1" Height="96px" />
```

Comment: We are not seeing any image related code in your post. Please clear on what you are asking.

Comment: Thats one of the image

Comment: You really better add the text to the image file name or build some mapping, otherwise you'll have to mess with OCR algorithms which are complicated and slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access the text used in a image directly in a code behind, until unless you do some image processing code.

It is better to set a `alt` and access it in a code behind.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img" ToolTip="My Image Text" ImageUrl="some.jpeg"/>
```

This will be rendered as

```
<img src="" alt="My Image Text" id="img" />
```

In Codebehind

```
string imageText=img.ToolTip
```

***Update:***

Use a hiddenfield to know which image with subcategories clicked

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img" ToolTip="My Image Text" 
onclick="setSelectedImage(this)" ImageUrl="some.jpeg"/>

<asp:HiddenField id="hdnSelected" runat="server" />
```

Javascript in a page

```
function setSelectedImage(obj)
{
  //based on your condition to check it has subcategories
   document.getElementById("<%= hdnSelected.ClientID %>").value=obj.id;
}
```

In Code behind

```
Image selectedImg=(Image)Page.FindControl(hdnSelected.Value);
string text=selectedImg.ToolTip
```

Comment: Thank you this is working but there is a problem. i need to get the text of only that image whose subcategory is selected.

Comment: @Maes, You need to set some flag to the image to identify whether subcategory is selected or not. Or keep a hidden field for which image was selected, update the hidden field with the selected image id using javascript. In code behind you can get the id from hidden and then use `(Image)Page.FindControl("idstoredInHidden")`

Comment: Can u make the explanation bit more specific,I don't have much idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the image text while adding the images.
If yes then you can add that text in data attribute and easily access it with js code.

```
<img id="temp" src="/images/43/jpg" data-text="43" />
```

Js Code

```
document.getElementById("temp").getAttribute("data-text");
```